# Implementing a generic type in repository

Tags: c#, generics, interface, implementation

Im not sure if what I'd like to do is possible since I haven't found anything on google and after about 30minutes of intensive search I decided to ask directly.

I have definded a simple interface for my repository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable
{
    TEntity GetById(object id);
    List<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

Now I want to implement my first repository and it works like this

```
public class ContentRepository : IRepository<ContentPages>
{
    private readonly Context _db = new Context();

    public ContentPages GetById(object id)
    {
        var result = _db.ContentPages.Find(id);
        return result;
    }

    public List<ContentPages> GetAll()
    {
        return _db.ContentPages.ToList();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This works fine but when I inject my repository to my mvc Controller it takes an `IRepository<ContentPages>` as parameter type and I just want it to take an `IRepository`.

I tried to move the generic type to the functions itself like this

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
    {
        TEntity GetById<TEntity>(object id);
        List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

When I do this I don't know how to define my generic type `TEntity` in the implementation

So in conclusion I want my use the interface without speficing a type so it gets the type from the actual object like this

```
public constructor1(IRepository ContentRepository){}
```

the next controller gets this constructor

```
public constructor2(IRepository BlogRepository){}
```

and so on

I hope I could describe my problem close enough for u guys to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the concrete implementation of `IRepository` Class you can define the type of the TEntity as follows.

```
  public TEntity GetById<TEntity>(object id) where TEntity:class
   {
    // Implimetation
   }
```

But in here according to repository pattern better to use as follows.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>: IDisposable where TEntity : class
```

Comment: When I use your first example and implement as follows:
return _db.ContentPages.Find(id);
I get cant convert ContentPages to TEntity
I cant say Tentity:ContentPages because it violates the interface

Answer (score 0):

try such variant:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);

    // ...
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(keyValues);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Example of usage:

```
IRepository<ApplicationUser> repository = new Repository<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
ApplicationUser applicationUser = repository.Find("key");
```

Also, there is a better solution - you can use pattern UnitOfWork. Check [this implementation on codeplex](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/). It is really cool.

Example:

```
public class DatabasesController : Controller
{
    private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private WebContext _context;

    public DatabasesController()
    {
        _context = new WebContext();
        _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_context);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Databases/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        List<Database> databases =
            _unitOfWork
            .Repository<Database>()
            .Query()
            .Include(database => database.FileEntitiesInfo)
            .Get()
            .ToList();
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        return View(databases);
    }
}
```